# How do I enclose a field with double quotes, using fgetcsv

Tags: php, fopen, delimiter, fgetcsv

I have this csv:

1629311007-1407,"[{""cats"":""Cat1""},{""cats"":""Cat2""}]",[],title

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$local_file = 'data.csv';
echo count(file($local_file)).' itens';

$fileHandle = fopen($local_file, "r");

while (($row = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 0, ',')) !== FALSE) {

  echo $row[0].'<br>';
  echo $row[1].'<br>';
  echo $row[2].'<br>';
 

}
?>
```

Output must be:

```
1629311007-1407
[{""cats"":""Cat1""},{""cats"":""Cat2""}]
title
```

But it's coming out like this

```
1629311007-1407
"[{""cats"":""Cat1""}
{""cats"":""Cat2""}]"
```

How can I adjust?

Comment: why not echo $row[3] instead of $row[2] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
($fileHandle,0,',','"');
```

Add the forth parameter in `fgetcsv` which will not break the comma between your strings that are between double quotes. So a comma between double quotes will be ignored and considered 1 field.

Comment: Thanks! Works.
Now my problem is encoding like VerÃ£o

Comment: I am glad i helped. This is a different question though so try to solve the encoding and if not you can create a new question :)